# What does "Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope" mean? Where to get more debug information?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a wordpress site. When running my site I get in the consle the following errors.

```
Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope 3 background.js:841:170
Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope ExtensionMessagingService.js:89:34
Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope 10 background.js:841:170
```

Maybe it has to do with a javascript that I also developed for that site. It is using getElementbyID.

I am not sure to what that error is related. Can somebody explain me what that error means? Is there a way to find more debug information than what is shown in the debug console? I am a newbie in website development.

Comment: sounds like an issue with one of your browser's extensions, try to deactivate them.

Answer (score 38):

Trusting the site in Ghostery got rid of this error for me (dev server on localhost)

Comment: Could be that issue: https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/issues/707

Comment: The next Ghostery release will have a fix.

Answer (score 13):

The "background.js:841:170" in the console log is a link, which when clicked on takes you to the offending code. Research indicates a moz extension, which seems to indicate an Adblocker.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

- click the link at the right end of the error message.
- It will open a new tab in your browser.
- On the the address bar(of that new tab) you will find the name of the extension[Extension(extension_name)] that is causing the problem.
- Disabling that extension stops this error message.

or you can simply change the browser. So suppose if you use firefox for browsing, then use chrome for development. Both have good developer tools.